# Pinax - account - how to modify template and views

Tags: python, django, django-templates, account, pinax

I installed Pinax (project-account) and it seems to work nicely. Now I would like to modify e.g. login page. I tried this by copying login.html to template dir of my app and modifying it, but it still seems to load login.html from installation of Pinax.

I don't believe that I should rewrite both view and template. So, how can I edit those default views and templates installed during Pinax installation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is struggling with same problem in the future:
1)Copy template to your app template dir.
2)Create your own view. Inherit original view, but override template name. On simplest form it could be like this:

```
from account.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = "login.html"
```

3)Modify urls.py of your app to point MyLoginView